# iterations getting skipped when removing from list while iterating

Tags: python, list

I'm not sure if I'm missing something, but I'm confused about this. I'm iterating over a list and removing some elements based on a condition. When the condition is met, it skips the next iteration. For example:

```
l = [1,1,2,3,1]
for i in l:
    print(f'checking {i} in {l}')
    if i == 1:
        print(f'removing')
        l.remove(i)
```

And this returns

```
checking 1 in [1, 1, 2, 3, 1]
removing
checking 2 in [1, 2, 3, 1]
checking 3 in [1, 2, 3, 1]
checking 1 in [1, 2, 3, 1]
removing
```

And then `l=[2,3,1]`. I think what is happening is that it's iterating by index, so when something is removed, the current index in the iteration is off by one. Is there a way to do this without skipping elements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never mutate container you're iterating over, until you're really know what you're doing – iterate over `l[:]`, remove from `l`.

Your understanding of problem is point on – `for` loop does not iterating over list values directly, changing the list size breaks indexing.